# sleep_until() and steady_clock loop drifting from real time in macOS

Tags: c++, c++11

Good evening everyone,
I'm trying to learn concurrency using the C++ Concurrency Book by Anthony Williams. Having read the first 2 chapters I thought about coding a simple metronome working in its own thread:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>

class Metro
{
public:
    // beats per minute
    Metro(int bpm_in);
    void start();

private:
    // In milliseconds
    int mPeriod;
    std::vector<std::thread> mThreads;

private:
    void loop();
};

Metro::Metro(int bpm_in):
    mPeriod(60000/bpm_in)
{}

void Metro::start()
{
    mThreads.push_back(std::thread(&Metro::loop, this));
    mThreads.back().detach();
}

void Metro::loop()
{
    auto x = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    while(true)
    {
        x += std::chrono::milliseconds(mPeriod);
        std::cout << "\a" << std::flush;
        std::this_thread::sleep_until(x);
    }
}
```

Now, this code seems to work properly, except for the time interval: the period (assuming bpm = 60 => mPeriod = 1000ms) is more than 1100ms. I read that sleep_until is not guaranteed to wake the process up exactly at the correct time (cppreference.com), but the lack of precision should not change the average period time, only delay the single "tic" inside the time grid, am I understanding it correctly? I assumed that storing the steady_clock::now() time only the first time and then using only the increment would be the correct way not to add drifting time at every cycle. Nevertheless, I also tried to change the x var update in the while loop to

```
x = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() + std::chrono::milliseconds(mPeriod);
```

but the period increases even more. I also tried using std::chrono::system_clock and high_resolution_clock, but the period didn't improve. Also, I think the properties I'm interested in for this application are monotonicity and steadiness, which steady_clock has. My question is: is there anything completely wrong I did in my code? Am I missing something concerning how to use std::chrono clocks and sleep_until? Or is this kind of method inherently not precise?

I've started analyzing the period by simply comparing it against some known metronomes (Logic Pro, Ableton Live, some mobile apps) and then recorded the output sound to have a better measurement. Maybe the sound buffer has some delay on itself, but same problem happens when making the program output a char. Also, the problem I'm concerned about is the drifting, not the single tic being a bit out of time.

I'm compiling from macos 10.15 terminal with g++ --std=c++11 -pthread and running it on Intel i7 4770hq.

Comment: `sleep_until` always sleeps for __at least__ the requested time not an average around the requested time.  When the thread is woken after the time has expired depends on the OS scheduler and what ever else the Computer/OS is doing.  Note that MS-WIndows , Linux and other similar OSes are not a real-time OS and all timings will be approximate.

Comment: While I understand that `sleep_until` sleeps for at least the requested time, I'm not updating x with the current time but only with the expected time it reached. For example, let's say `sleep_until` always sleeps for 20ms more, because of other os processes. At x = 1000, the real time is 1020. At that point, x doesn't carry the error with it, because it updates on 1000, so it becomes 2000. At this point, `sleep_until` oversleeps again, but calculated from the 2000 value it has as argument, so it wakes up at 2020, having slept 1000 instead of the correct 980.

Comment: Your code looks fine and also runs fine for me on a macOS machine; the period is exactly as expected. Not all clocks are equal though, and it could be that your clock crystal has a large drift, although 10% is extreme and not something I would expect on Mac hardware.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to run it locally! Is there any way I could check for the precision of my clock crystal?